# Convert publish profile file (.xml) into DacDeployOptions class

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac, dac

I am working on a C# project where I should deploy few .dacpac files so I have used the [Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx) library (github from DacFx [here](https://github.com/microsoft/DacFx)).

I have used also in another part the SqlPackage.exe executable to deploy another .dacpac files (no relation between them), so I'm using a publish profile (.xml / .pubxml file) to configure the deployment options. The cmd command looks like this:

```
SqlPackage /Profile:"Database.publish.xml"
```

I would need to deserialize this .xml file into a [DacDeployOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.dacdeployoptions?view=sql-dacfx-150) class in order to use the same pulish profile when publishing the dacpacs, but as much as I have been able to search I can't find a way to do it. I would appreciate some help with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long search I found the solution. Here the needed Code:

```
DacProfile profile = DacProfile.Load(@"C:\temp\publish.xml");
PublishOptions options = new PublishOptions();
options.GenerateDeploymentReport = true;
options.GenerateDeploymentScript = true;
options.DeployOptions = profile.DeployOptions;
```